# Electrons, Electric Current

Tags: electric-current

In a DC circuit through a wire, is saying:

> " Electrons are a flow of matter and electric charge. Protons are a
>   flow of electric current and matter. "

the same as saying Electric Current/Electric Energy flows from the positive terminal through/by protons to the negative terminal while at the same time electrons with their electric charge flow from the negative terminal to the positive terminal.

If so, then an extension question the first is; why then is it said that in a DC circuit through a wire, it doesn't matter which way the current is said to flow as long as you are consistent with which ever one you pick in using it in the circuit,

> if very clearly it is true that electric current and energy start from
>   the positive terminal and flow to the negative.

EDIT:

> " Electrons and protons are matter, not energy. A flow of electrons is
>   NOT a flow of energy, it is a flow of matter and a flow of electric
>   charge. Same goes for protons: moving protons are electric current,
>   but they're also a matter-flow.

Comment: Where are you taking the quote from?  Where "is it said that..."?  Where are you getting your ideas from?

Comment: @sammygerbil 3. Electrons are a kind of energy particle? Wrong. 

Electrons and protons are matter, not energy. A flow of electrons is NOT a flow of energy, it is a flow of matter and a flow of electric charge. Same goes for protons: moving protons are electric current, but they're also a matter-flow. And most important: if you have a certain amount of charge in one place, you'll have no clue about the amount of energy present. Charge is not energy. And if charge is flowing along, you won't know anything about the energy's flow or direction.

Comment: @sammygerbil Coulombs are not Joules, and knowing the amount charge does not tell you the amount of energy you have. A moving electron does not carry electrical energy along with it, any more than a moving air molecule carries a sound wave with it.

Comment: Yes, I see that you have made exactly the same comments to Kari below.  So you are trying to teach people?  Then you don't have a question which can be answered.

Comment: @sammygerbil how so. when  " is saying X statement the same as Y statement " ASKED, then I don't see why I have answerless question.

Comment: I think that you are asking for a discussion about the Misconceptions in K6 Textbooks document.  This is not the appropriate place for a discussion.  I suggest that you visit the ChatRooms section of the website : http://chat.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @sammygerbil No, you misunderstood. I am not asking for a discussion about misconceptions. I took a text from a article about misconceptions and ASKING what I asked above.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what question(s) you are asking.  Please can you edit your question to make it clear what you do not understand about physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil Is the sentence in quotations the same as the sentence under it. And if so, then what is the answer to the extension question under all of them.

Comment: @sammygerbil the question is self explanatory and will not be rewritten differently. The question is about the electrodynamic area of physics.

Comment: @sammygerbil question has been edited.

Comment: @MacR. *"A flow of electrons is NOT a flow of energy"* Well, strictly speaking, an object or particle in motion has kinetic energy - so a moving electron contains kinetic energy and so in this sense, energy *does* flow along with the electron flow.

Comment: I have some agreement with you there, but it would be of some clarity if you look further where all this has originated from. And i know that this is in a different direction of the topic but it still holds water. http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html#frkel question question #3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **no**, the two statements do not mean the same thing. And the reason is that they are both incorrect in their details.

> **Statement 1:** *"Electrons are a flow of matter and electric charge. Protons are a flow of electric current and matter."*

Electrons and protons are not a flow of anything, they are just particles (and they both have mass and charge). If they move we might call that a flow. And charges flowing is called *electric current*.

> **Statement 2:** *"Electric Current/Electric Energy flows from the positive terminal through/by protons to the negative terminal while at the same time electrons with their electric charge flow from the negative terminal to the positive terminal."*

- Let's first get the definition clear: A **terminal** is the name of the end of a battery (so if the circuit contains no battery or some similar source, this makes no sense to mention). The **positive terminal** is the battery-end with **highest electric potential**.

Now, try to follow me in the next few lines of thought:

1. Electrons as negative charge are gathered at the **negative terminal**.
2. They repel each other, so electrons are squeezed up to the **positive terminal**. (You can say that they are repelled from the negative or attracted by the positive terminal - either way gives same result).
3. These **electrons flowing** is **charge flowing** so this is called **an electric current**.

Protons are not flowing in metal wire circuits, only electrons. In general, as another answer points out, the flow of charge doesn't have to be electrons (or protons), it could also be ions or "holes" and so on. That depends on the type of circuit. So in general, we can simply call it **positive charge carriers** and **negative charge-carriers**.

> why then is it said that in a DC circuit through a wire, it doesn't matter which way the current is said to flow as long as you are consistent with which ever one you pick in using it in the circuit, if very clearly it is true that electric current and energy start from the positive terminal and flow to the negative.

The answer is: **Because people had to agree on something** to talk about circuit in general.

Your second statement above was almost correct except the fact that protons do not move, only electrons do (when we are talking about regular usual wire-circuit). This is good to know to understand what happens - but it is not necessary to know if you just wish to work with circuits. Because

- *negative charge (electrons) moving from negative to positive terminal* corresponds directly to
- ***positive charge*** moving the other way.

Even if no positive charge actually moves, this is how it looks from the outside.

So, as mentioned, in some types of circuits (e.g. ion-based), positive (and negative) charge *does* move, while in others (wire-circuits) it doesn't and only negative charge moves. To avoid these details every time, we just always say that positive charge is moving as well.

**And to agree on something**, it has simply been chosen that the direction of current is always in the direction of the positive charge. Sometimes positive charge *is* moving, and sometimes it isn't and we don't care unless we need to look deeper into what charge-carriers we actually have.

Comment: " while in others (wire-circuits) it doesn't and only negative charge moves. " based on that sentence ELECTRIC CURRENT is negative. That is, it starts and " moves/flows/bumps " out of the Negative terminal in a progressive direction to the positive terminal. Whether " we" humans agreed to the  " positive " definition of electric current  is irrelevant because your sentence states that through a wire electric current is NEGATIVE.

Comment: @MacR. It is just a matter of words, yes. If you by saying that *"electric current is NEGATIVE"* mean that "electric current is constituted of negative charge-carriers"*, then you are absolutely right - but only for this type of wire-circuits.

Comment: I used a DC circuit with wire as a conductor for this question.

Comment: @MacR. Good for you. You are welcome to say that the current moves from negative to positive terminal if you also say *what* is moving (electrons in this case). Otherwise, if you just state that current moves in some direction, it is not enough and I can't know what you mean. Because of that issue, it has ben chosen that whenever someone just says that current moves in some direction, then that means that *positive* charge would be moving in that direction. Then we all know what is meant.

Comment: when I deal with 480 v 100 amp + power everyday at work I want to have the WORDS just right. An misguided error could cost me a lot.

Comment: " You are welcome to say that the current moves from negative to positive terminal " it is what SHOULD be always said in this type of circuit. " Otherwise, if you just state that current moves in some direction, it is not enough and I can't know what you mean. " I agree.

Comment: @MacR. That is a matter of personal opinion. For this type of circuit, yes. But as I said, the definition has been made in order to avoid having to distinguish between *types* of circuits.

Comment: and what " type " of circuit did I bring up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your first statement, "Electrons are a flow of matter and electric charge. Protons are a flow of electric current and matter," because it's simply wrong. Electrons are fundamental particles with various properties and protons are a combination of up and down quarks. They both have a charge and create a current when in motion but they are not "flows of matter" nor electric charge or current.

As for your second question, the reason it doesn't matter which way you say the current flows as long as you're consistent, is that a flow of positive charges in one direction is (as far as charge distribution is concerned) equivalent to a flow of negative charges in the opposite direction.

Comment: 3. Electrons are a kind of energy particle? Wrong. 

Electrons and protons are matter, not energy. A flow of electrons is NOT a flow of energy, it is a flow of matter and a flow of electric charge. Same goes for protons: moving protons are electric current, but they're also a matter-flow. And most important: if you have a certain amount of charge in one place, you'll have no clue about the amount of energy present. Charge is not energy. And if charge is flowing along, you won't know anything about the energy's flow or direction.

Comment: Coulombs are not Joules, and knowing the amount charge does not tell you the amount of energy you have. A moving electron does not carry electrical energy along with it, any more than a moving air molecule carries a sound wave with it.

Comment: - That' was taken from this site http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html#frkel

Comment: None of what you are saying is even remotely relevant to the question or my answer.

Comment: @MacR. : Are you asking about something you do not understand?  Or are you trying to teach people that their way of thinking is incorrect?

Comment: @MacR. You seem to be very confused about this subject in general, I suggest reading a coherent and comprehensive text about this subject such as Jackson or Zangwill, or the relevant chapters of a reliable freshman's physics book.

Comment: @V.KáriDaníelsson of course it is. If you are saying not it's not and this is saying yes it is, then it is relevant to your answer. And of course it's relevant to the question because it's in reference to whether or not electric current does or does not flow with protons from the positive terminal to the negative terminal.

Comment: @sammygerbil I am trying to get to bottom of something. Whether it teaches someone (me included) something or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @V.KáriDaníelsson so you are saying that the text I provided you was in incoherent and uncomprehensive. Alright then. I'm going to ask you to prove it.

Comment: @MacR. Indeed, the resource you have been linking is not a comprehensive account of it's subject nor does it attempt to be. Incoherent isn't really the right way to describe it, but no, the website does not have a well structured narrative nor does it intend to. It is supplementary reading to address several misconceptions many people might develop when learning electrodynamics, and does this quite well. What you're asking for is not something that can be put down in a Q/A format, I think the best thing you can do is take your time with an actual textbook.

Comment: @V.KáriDaníelsson I have and do. But the site does bring about things that are factual in it's direction of the subject. Either way, what I am asking for is valid even if the text is in another direction about the subject because it has stated X, Y, Z points about the subject that if hold to be factual bring us back to my question. If the statement in quotations are true then is it the same as the statement under it. If the statement is not, alright then, but why not.

Comment: I believe the point here is that the linked website adresses certain specific issues, but it doesn't give a very good overview. For a good overview  and general understanding, this might not be the best source.

Answer (score 0):

Electrons and protons are not a flow of anything.  They are particles which have charge and energy (along with other properties).  Electric current is a flow of charge.

No the first statement (indented) is not the same as that underneath it.  Electric current in metal wires is usually a flow of electrons from the -ve terminal to the +ve. But in some cases (eg in semi-conductors) it can be a flow of 'holes' which are the absence of bound electrons.  Unlike conduction electrons which are not attached to any particular atom, 'holes' are bound to atoms and jump from one atom to the next.

In answer to your 2nd question, usually it does not matter which way round current flows because all we want to know is how much current is flowing, not which direction it is going.  This is especially true where the current is alternating and flows in both directions (though not at the same time).

Comment: " Electric current is a flow of charge " and if that is so then per the text provided in the question and comments it be starting from a positive terminal going to the negative terminal. And per common text in accepted academia the common explanation of charge flow is " given " to be from negative to positive by the step-by-step thought  branching from the explanation that electrons with their charge are all that " flows " in the DC circuit through wire.

Comment: " Electric current is a flow of electrons (or positive charges). " http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21392/current-in-a-simple-circuit

Comment: You seem to be trying to prove a point rather than ask a question.

Comment: I am following up your answer with relevant information because it your answer seems incorrect. And as grateful as I am for your efforts, I am trying to get some correct answers to my question.

Comment: I see nothing incorrect in this answer, @MacR, but if you do, please point it out clearly to the author instead of just adding a chunk of further information that seems to come out of the blue.

Comment: @Steeven I did when I gave a link of someone stating information that is correct. " point it out ", I assumed everyone here was able to read.

Comment: @Steeven hey steeven, if Sammy wants to contend why I denied her answer, let her do it. she's a big girl. You got the answer already, why bother.

Comment: @MacR. My curiosity luckily overcomes my need to be right. And here, my curiosity wants to find out, what part of this answer you find incorrect.

Comment: @MacR : If you do not like my answer, that is ok.  The problem is that you do not seem to like any answer.  The only correct answer is your answer.  So why don't you post your own answer?

Comment: @sammygerbil someone has not got the answer already, namely steven.

Comment: @Steeven backtracking my dialogue with Sammy, I made an error in READING, namely the text I submitted from the link I gave. It wasn't so much " finding " incorrectness as it was proofreading (failingly) for it when I said " it seems ". So Sammy's answer although factually correct, was still incomplete to fulfill the needs of the question and it's errors.